# How to display more copies of an object?

Tags: ios, swift

**Objective**

I need my app to display multiple instances of a `UIImageView`. In other words, the app should take a `UIImageView` and display it more times inside a view. The new `UIImageViews` remain identical, only their position in the view changes.

**Code**

To do so, I firstly declare a `UIImageView`:

```
    let myImage = UIImage(named: "house")
    let myImageView = UIImageView(image: myImage)

    myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.size.width/2, view.frame.size.height/2, 100, 100)
```

I then use a `for-loop` to repeat the image repetition.

```
    for (var i = 0; i != 10; i++) {
        // Distribuite UIIMageViews here

        self.view.addSubview(myImageView)
    }
```

Though, I seem to find no way to copy a `UIImageView` and display it more times. Declaring more than one `UIImageView` sounds like an inefficient solution to me.

**Question**

Is there any way to display an object (`UIImageView`) multiple times by declaring it just once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `UIImageView` doesn't conform to the [NSCopying](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/index.html) protocol, you will have to do the copy yourself: instantiate a new `UIImageView` and copy manually each property you think important from the original to the new one.

The following example is creating 10 new images based on the original one. They are just copying the `UIImage`, but you can complete it and copy the properties you need:

```
let myImage = UIImage(named: "house")
let myImageView = UIImageView(image: myImage)
myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.size.width/2, view.frame.size.height/2, 100, 100)
self.view.addSubview(myImageView)
for (var i = 0; i != 10; i++) {
    var newImageView = UIImageView(image: myImageView.image)
    newImageView.frame = // yourNewFrame
    // Copy any else properties you need from the original image
    self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question! How do I copy the `UIImageView`? Would you mind linking some methods that could help me doing that? Thanks!